# C++ run a task in secondary thread and expect a response on main thread

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have to run a task in background using thread in C++. Actually in code i have to send multiple HTTP request using curl and i don't want to run using Main thread as it will put main thread blocked untill task is completed. Hence I want for each http request is should be something like that :

a) a new thread is created b) send the curl req on this new thread c) once req/response is done, send response/data back to main thread

During this process i want Main thread to be free and run some other its own task. I am new to C++ and threading, please advise how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your main thread to be notified as soon as the worker thread is done then it sounds like you need to have a message processing loop in the main thread.

I'm just thinking this can be implemented the same way as the window procedure in WinAPI. Something along these lines.

```
cEvent event;
while( true )
{
  event = GetNextEvent();
  if( event.GetType() == APPQUIT )
  {
    break;
  }
  if( event.GetType() == SENDHHPTREQUEST )
  {
    // Create worker thread etc.
  }
  else if( event.GetType() == HTTPREQUESTCOMPLETED )
  {
    // Process HTTP request resuts.
  }
  ...
}
```

The worker thread needs a way to send events to the main thread. And of course adding, removing events from the message queue must be thread-safe, i.e. protected with mutexes. And I guess all the data required to create a request or to process results of a request needs to be somehow packaged into cEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a condition variable or auto or manual reset event to notify your main thread.  You get your main thread to wait for this condition variable when you've started your secondary thread, and when the secondary thread is done, it signal's the flag which lets the main thread know it's done and can continue doing what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using c++11 standard, I had to make a "main thread caller" which takes a lambda of code and schedules it to call on main thread next time the screen updates (which is always on the main thread). Internally it uses a vector of lambdas and drains it every time update is called. If there is no lambdas, update is not scheduled. I use it extensively in my iOS/Droid production code.
you can get it here:
https://github.com/radif/emjCCMainThreadCaller